# IE not displaying dropdown panel properly

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I'm trying to figure out why my site appears to be displaying a dropdown panel ok in FF, Chrome etc., but not in Internet Explorer (7+ as I don't support IE6 now):

http://www.thelivingleader.com/

The image on the lefthand side is disappearing, the link with id #offerbtn isn't styled properly and the panel shows by default. I'm also getting an error message from IE saying:

> The instruction at "0x3fa07838" referenced memory at "0x000000008". The memory could not be "read".

Could it be to do with my jQuery statements in the footer of the document? Any help figuring out what's going wrong here massively appreciated...

Thanks

Osu

*Edit* - here's the code: http://www.pastie.org/2541961

Comment: Some relevant code posted herewould be very helpful, thank you ;)

Comment: @Caspar Kleijne - thanks for getting back to me. The code I'm talking about is everything within '<offer id="slidedown">...</offer>' - here's the code: http://www.pastie.org/2541961

Comment: what is the _offer_ tag? did you create that in the document? Does the browser know it exists?

Comment: @Caspar Kleijne - this is a HTML5 document, so <offer> is just acting as a div - do you think that could be the problem?

Comment: @Caspar Kleijne - you were right! If you add this as an answer below, then I'll credit you with the answer. Thanks for raising it! Only thing I need to figure out now is why the image is not displaying correctly in IE (I'm assuming it's the width of the table cell, but that's a different question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An element that does not exist in the HTML specs will be **ignored** or at least behave very bad in IE. Other browsers *might* accept it, but for **future compliancy** I would encourage you to stick to the **HTML specs**.

The `offer` element is unknown, so will be rendered depending on the browser's goodness towards your document. IE7 will crunch it.

But how about tablet browsers, Linux browsers and all others?

Comment: Dankjuwel Caspar! Couldn't have put it better - here's a link for those of you who make the same mistake as me (there are pre-defined semantic divs in HTML5, something I didn't know!): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/hh410106#_HTML5_Semantic_Elements

Comment: IN Ie you can do a *document.createElement* in the header and define the custom element before the browser starts rendering so it might work.